# Access globally configured data from Builder and Notifier

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to extend the [Jenkins Xcode plugin](https://www.github.com/jenkinsci/xcode-plugin) and want to integrate a post build step.

The current state of the plugin allows to configure keychains via the Jenkins settings page. Therefore it implements a Descriptor and overwrites it's `configure` method. The UI is defined in the `global.jelly` file.

Now I want to access the keychains that are configured from another class. I created a subclass of `hudson.tasks.Notifier` (the class lays in the same package as the `XCodeBuilder` class) which itself contains a class subclassing `BuildStepDescriptor<Builder>`. Basically I copied the contents of the `BuildStepDescriptor` inside the [`XCodeBuilder`](https://github.com/mAu888/xcode-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/au/com/rayh/XCodeBuilder.java) class, but when trying to display the contents of the `keychains` property, it says that there are zero elements (when doing a `System.out.println`). The UI itself for the post build step is displaying fine.

My Java knowledge is kind of rusty and these are my first steps extending Jenkins. So maybe I'm not even able to access this data from within the plugin, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question for the searching people on the web. I followed the solution proposed [here](http://jieryn.blogspot.de/2012/02/jenkins-plugin-protip.html).

- Create a class that inherits from [`jenkins.model.GlobalConfiguration`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/GlobalConfiguration.html).
- Put the logic for global configuration from your `Descriptor` class into the newly created one.
- Make sure you have a `config.jelly` in a subfolder named after your class.
- Where you need to access the global configuration, use a private non-final class member and annotate it with `@Inject` (`javax.inject.Inject`).

First I placed the private member variable for the build step inside the build step class itself, and tried to access it via `${instance.getGlobalConfiguration().getProperty()}` in my jelly. But that did not work, as the instance for a newly not yet saved build step does not exist. So I placed the private member inside the `Descriptor` of the build step and accessed it via `${descriptor.getGlobalConfiguration().getProperty()}` and voilà, there you go.